# mongorestore error "parsing positional arguments: provide only one polling interval in seconds and only one MongoDB connection string"

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have been trying to mongorestore data that was sent to me (a file containing bson data and json metadata of course), unfortunately with zero success. I keep getting the same error: "error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one polling interval in seconds and only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes", no matter what i do. I have tried:

"mongorestore mongodb://localhost:27017 -d mydb C:...file location"

"mongorestore --host="localhost:27017" C:...file location"

"mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017  C:...file location"

"mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 -d mydb C:...file location

But nothing.
Can someone please help and point me to what I am missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are running `mongod` on your Windows machine.

```
mongorestore --db mydb C:\databaseDump\mydb
```

Comment: The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}